# README.md: how to substitute a key value from a file

Tags: markdown, readme

Parameterization of the **readme.md** file. It is necessary to render the value on the remote github repository using the key specified in the raw **readme.md** file of the project.

Example:

1. Contents of the **.env** file:

   ```
   root_path=/opt/dirname
   ```
2. [EXAMPLE] **readme.md** (raw):

   ```
   Current path- `${{root_path}}`
   ```
3. **readme.md** (github):

   ```
   Current path: /opt/dirname
   ```

How to do it?